# What's the most semantic way to mark up arbitrary pieces of text?

Tags: html

We're having a debate here at work about placing arbitrary text (such as a statement / motto) directly inside a `<div>` tag.

One suggests this is the most semantic and valid way to markup this code, while another says that the text should be wrapped in a P tag inside the side.

What are your thoughts?

```
<div class="section-header inner">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ALIPINISIM-e1452270752934.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">From first steps to the biggest objectives, a British Mountain Guide is an expert in techniques and safety, and a reliable companion for your adventures.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do the people promoting the use of `p` say is the reason for doing that?

Comment: I find it quite intriguing that the debate going on in the office is also being replicated here at stack overflow. I guess it comes down to personal preference as to "what is" the best way to mark up this particular section of the website. :)

Comment: Firstly I'd ask what it is you actually want to achieve by giving the text any sort of semantic tag...  If nothing, just leave the text raw inside the `<div>`.

Comment: shouldn't this actually be on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?   There's no coding question here, just HTML semantics.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could do this depending on what the text is trying to convey. `<blockquote>` comes to mind initially. `<section>` is another way to do it depending again on the usage.

In your example I am assuming that the text goes with the image, so in that case I would use `<figure>` with a `<figcaption>` inside it. Inside the `.section-header inner`.

Does that answer your question?

As an afterthought, there is the option to use `hgroup` which is for the heading of a section, but not given a level like conventional `h1, h2,` etc.

There is also things like `<b>` which are less semantic but are usually reserved for text that is just stylistically different.

Comment: I thought `blockquote` at first, but MDN says it's reserved for extended quotes. Thus I personally went with `q`.

Comment: Actually, the quote in the example is longer than I thought. `blockquote` could in fact be a good choice.

Comment: That's fair. I did mention that it depends largely on what you intend the text to be. I mean as something with no meaning, I would say there are even half a dozen ways to mark it up semantically.

Comment: But it's neither a block quote, nor a section, nor a figcaption. It's just some text.

Comment: In the case it is literally just text with no meaning... just a standard `<p>` should do the trick. Put a class or an id on it in the case of styling if it has special style rules.

Comment: won't a `<p>` inside a `<div>` potentially get additional margins, etc, compared to just putting the text directly inside the `<div>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if my page contained a brief, arbitrary string, I wouldn't give it any semantic weighting i.e. the snippet you shared. I feel that `p` elements should be reserved for breaking down continuous flows of text.

Given your context of a statement or motto, you could potentially use a [`q`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q) element, especially if you wished it to attribute it to someone.

Comment: There is an option backend to indeed attribute the text to a person. The overlay then contains a blockquote wrapper for the text, and then the attributed person inside that

Comment: `q` is not such a good idea. In many systems/frameworks, `q` will have quoting behavior associated with it.

Comment: @torazaburo That's true, but one shouldn't really consider aesthetics when considering how to make markup semantic; it's purely a problem of representing information in a meaningful way. Plus I'd personally override styles if needed. This issue affects many other elements too.

Comment: A `q` is for a quote. What the OP showed is not a quote. Ergo, `q` is wrong.

Comment: Looking at the example again, I think @jensenmk89's `figure/figcaption` combo would be good. That said, avoiding `q` simply for aesthetics isn't a good reason. Additionally, one may wish to attribute it to the user who entered the caption into the system.

Answer (score -1):

Is it a paragraph?

Paragraphs should be marked up with `<p>` elements.

Comment: Its just brief text that sits over an image in a carousel. Could be one word, could be 10 words, or in this example many words

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that the statement in the example is a paragraph. I've elaborated in my answer.

Comment: @Anto — So? Take them on a case by case basis. Is the text a paragraph? If it is, it should be marked up as such.

Comment: @JamesWright — The statement here is that paragraphs should be marked up with `<p>` elements. I'm avoiding dealing with the English grammar component of the question.

Comment: This may be "correct" but only as far as it goes. It fails to answer the question of how to mark it up if it's not a paragraph. Whether or not it's a paragraph is not a question of English grammar. It's a question of the role of the snippet of text within the web page. For instance, normally `p` tags have built-in margins.

Comment: I agree with @torazaburo. Plus semantic HTML is so open to interpretation.

Comment: How can it be dealt with on a case by case basis, if it is the customer deciding the text that sits within the overlay? They may type a paragraph to which a P tag would be better, but they may also type one word in which a P tag would be wasted markup?